# Generate and download excel on fly and show loader to user while file is ready to download

Tags: javascript, java, apache-poi

I am trying to create excel using poi at server side and sending it to browser.
Using href or form submit solution is working fine but tricky part is file creation taking too much time so i want to show user some message like "Processing file" so I have implemented this using simple get request and added loader before request and removed in success call back.

Problem is - instead of downloading file, file contain coming as responseText at client side and also always executes failure call back.
Please suggest how i can get file as download in success call  back instead of byte data in response text.
Also tried to set content type as attachment, force download etc but nothing work for me browser not downloading file it's showing byte data in response text
Tried to open new window with download url but as mentioned file creation take time so browser shows no content error after few minute.

**note hwb is workbook object in below code**

```
file = new File(FileName+"_"+timeStamp+".xlsx");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
hwb.write(fos);
fos.close();
file.deleteOnExit();

String contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file, contentType);
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ file.getName());
return response.build();
```

Comment: Are you using Ajax for request?

Comment: @ Saurabh Yes I am using Ajax request of type GET